# Rename file and move to folder Powershell

Tags: batch-file, rename, regexp-replace, batch-rename

I have some PDF files that I need to rename and move to specific folders to be able to import into a system.
The file by default has the following name:
ex: 12345.123456/1234-12.pdf

First I need to remove the characters "," "/" "-"

```
@echo off
setlocal EnabledelayedExpansion
for /r "C:\importation" %%a in (*) do (
set "newname=%%~na"
set "newname=!newname:.=!"
set "newname=!newname:-=!"
set "newname=!newname:/=!"
ren "%%~a" "!newname!%%~xa"
)
```

Now I need to create folders with the filename (without the characters removed, ex: 12345123456123412) and rename them to the following pattern:
ex: P12345123456123412_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf

For that I drag the files to the following script:

```
@If Not "%~1" == "" For %%G In (%*) Do @MD "%%~dpG%%~nG" 2>NUL && Move /Y "%%~G" "%%~dpG%%~nG\P%%~nG_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume%%~xG"
```

I would like to do only one process, that is, join the two scripts and run only once.
Can someone help me?

Rather than dragging the files to the batch file I would like to run it and have it read the files (.pdf) from the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

The following will accept drag and drop of one or more files **or** directories, *(subject to command line length restrictions)*. Each individually dropped PDF file and each PDF file within any dropped directory should be processed as requested.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1" == "" GoTo :EOF
For %%G In (%*) Do (For %%H In ("%%~G") Do If "%%~aH" Lss "-" (
        Echo Error! %%G no longer exists.
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL
    ) Else If "%%~aH" GEq "d" (For %%I In ("%%~G\*.pdf") Do Call :Sub "%%~I"
    ) Else If /I "%%~xG" == ".pdf" (Call :Sub "%%~G"
    ) Else (Echo Error! %%G is not a PDF
        %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL))
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "basename=%~n1"
Set "basename=%basename:.=%"
MD "%~dp1%~n1" 2>NUL
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%~n1\P%basename:-=%_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume%~x1"
Exit /B
```

Please note, as the character `/` is invalid in file or directory names, I have ignored that part of your question.

Comment: Perfect, it worked the way I wanted, thank you very much @compo